# Surface view on Android

Tags: android

I want to change the size of surface view at run time when it is changed to Landscape Mode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use different layout files

Comment: You can also use onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)